Storing binary values in Apache Ignite - Not inserted into SQL table
I have created a simple Apache Ignite setup that I hope to use for SQL later, but I want to construct it via the Java API for now. It is intended to be dynamic, so I can't use a POJO class for insertion. Unfortunately, I get this warning, and stepping through the GridQueryProcessor code in a debugger reveals no obvious fixes. I suspect that part of it is that my type() call is always null (variable b, printed as b=null), but I'm not sure.
Log output:
...snip
b=null
WARN GridQueryProcessor - Key-value pair is not inserted into any SQL table [cacheName=TestTable, valType=BinaryObject.TestTable_value]
WARN GridQueryProcessor -   ^-- Value type(s) are specified via CacheConfiguration.indexedTypes or CacheConfiguration.queryEntities
WARN GridQueryProcessor -   ^-- Make sure that same type(s) used when adding Object or BinaryObject to cache
WARN GridQueryProcessor -   ^-- Otherwise, entries will be stored in cache, but not appear as SQL Table rows
--------Inserted
...snip

And the full source code:

package snippet;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

import javax.cache.Cache.Entry;

import org.apache.ignite.*;
import org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObject;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.*;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.*;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.*;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder;
import org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler;

public class Snippet
{
    public static void main(String... strings) throws InterruptedException
    {
        /* This enables SLF4J to intercept JUL logging */
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
        Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.WARNING);

        // Start up our node
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setDeploymentMode(DeploymentMode.CONTINUOUS);
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(ipFinder));
        var ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

        System.err.println("--------Started");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        ///////// create table
        var cachec = new CacheConfiguration<>("TestTable");
        var qe = new QueryEntity();
        qe.addQueryField("simpleId", Long.TYPE.getName(), null);
        qe.addQueryField("stringField", String.class.getName(), null);
        qe.setKeyType("TestTable_key");
        qe.setIndexes(Collections.singleton(new QueryIndex("simpleId")));
        qe.setValueType("TestTable_value");
//      cachec.setStoreKeepBinary(true); // seems to have no effect
        cachec.setQueryEntities(Collections.singleton(qe));
        cachec.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
        cachec.setQueryParallelism(6);
        ignite.createCache(cachec);

        System.err.println("--------Created");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        /////// insert a row
        var bb = ignite.binary().builder("BinaryObject.TestTable_value");
        var b = ignite.binary().type("TestTable_value"); // always null for some reason
        System.err.println(b == null ? "b=null" : "b=not null");
        bb.setField("stringField", "it works!");
        bb.setField("simpleId", 3l);
        ignite.cache("TestTable").withKeepBinary().put(3l, bb.build());

        System.err.println("--------Inserted");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        
        /////// clean up
        ignite.destroyCache("TestTable");
        ignite.close();
    }
}

The project pom: (runnable with mvn clean compile exec:exec)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>Stack OverFlow Ignite Question</name>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-ignite-soq</artifactId>
    <version>12345</version>

    <properties>
        <ignite.version>2.16.0</ignite.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>

                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.access=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.sql/java.sql=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>snippet.Snippet</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


And the logback configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="console"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</configuration>

Edit: I added the pom, logback, and logging setup

I suggest that you take a look at the documentation for creating and working with Binary Objects: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/key-value-api/binary-objects
Hope that helps!

I did check the documentation prior to asking this question, but I can't figure out the issue. Could you expand on the specific part of the documentation? Answers should  " avoid making it necessary to click on [links] as much as possible." (from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer )

When you get your builder reference:
var bb = ignite.binary().builder("BinaryObject.TestTable_value");
The name should be the cache name and only the cache name.
No periods, no underscores, unless your cache name has underscores.
Hope that helps.

Trying several permutations, I can't get any to not output this warning, whether it's just "TestTable" or something fancier

The short answer is that Ignite is not really designed to work dynamically in the way you suggest. Tables in Ignite have schema(s). You can actually have multiple schemas per table, but you don't want to be in a situation where every row is different.
You at least want a situation where most columns are the same; otherwise, you won't be able to execute SQL queries against it.
Ignite provides a warning because the record you insert does not match the SQL schema you defined (with the query entities).
See the documentation for how to configure query entities.
Update after comment
Updated again. Converted to thick-client. Tested using Ignite 2.16.
No, you've not correctly defined your query entities. The equivalent of your CREATE TABLE command would be something like this:
        var cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration()
                .setName("CACHE2")
                .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
                .setBackups(1)
                .setSqlSchema("PUBLIC")
                .setQueryEntities(
                        Collections.singleton(
                                new QueryEntity()
                                        .setKeyType("java.lang.Integer")
                                        .setValueType("AnythingYouLike")
                                        .addQueryField("simpleId", "java.lang.Integer", null)
                                        .addQueryField("stringField", "java.lang.String", null)
                                        .addQueryField("longField", "java.lang.Long", null)
                                        .setKeyFieldName("simpleId")
                                        .setTableName("TEST_TABLE")
                        )
                );
        var cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfig).withKeepBinary();
        cache.put(1,ignite.binary()
                .builder("AnythingYouLike")
                .setField("stringField", "Hello")
                .setField("longField", 2L)
                .build());


Then how does SQL work? I can run the following without warnings: CREATE TABLE TestTable(simpleId int PRIMARY KEY, stringField VARCHAR); INSERT INTO TestTable(simpleId, stringField) VALUES (1,'Tester');. Does ignite generate a class?
I also am fairly confident that I defined the query entity correctly, did I not?

I updated my answer with a corrected query entity definition.

Hmm, How would I have more than two fields in a schema then, do I call .setValueFieldName("thirdField") and so on? Which field's value type would I pick for setValueType? Finally, I still get this warning, though slightly different this time: Key-value pair is not inserted into any SQL table [cacheName=TestTable, val=CacheObjectImpl [val=null, hasValBytes=true]]

I updated the answer again, but I would urge you to read the documentation more closely.

Could you provide a link to the documentation talking about how to create a query entity? I can't find anything about it on the main doc site. Also, once I fix the type errors in your code, it still gives me the same warning. Am I not supposed to be using org.apache.ignite:ignite-core:2.16.0 ?

My answer includes a link to the documentation. I updated the sample code to use thick-client APIs, and tested with Ignite 2.16. No warnings.

I appreciate your patience, but I still get the same (orignal) warnings with your latest code. I've updated the question with the pom & logback config in my question, and additionally posted the full version using your code at https://gist.github.com/byteit101/7a6e117fb3d59395622c5525320ee082 Do you not have JUL & SLF4J logging enabled? Does my original question show the warnings for you?
